# How redirect query search result from domain which contains a folder?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have this code in my .htacces file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ job\?search_keywords=%1 [NC,R,L]
```

And it works well for: `example.com/?s=blabla`

Now I would like to add that if the url contains **/en/**:

```
https://example.com/en/?s=blabla
```

change for `https://example.com/en/work/?search_keywords=blabla`

Somone could help me with it? Because my trying gives me ERROR 500.

Comment: `https://example.com/en/work/search_keywords=blabla` is strange as it has no `?` but has a part like query parameter.

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried in order to redirect the `/en` Uri ?

Comment: @anubhava Oh, my mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need another rule to handle new URI pattern:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /job?search_keywords=%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/?$ /en/work/?search_keywords=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Note that `\\?` in your `RewriteCond` is redundant as `QUERY_STRING` variable doesn't contain `?`